# Cloud Build failing to npm install a NodeJS project

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform, npm-install, google-cloud-build

I'm running the following command in my `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["install"]
```

This command ran correctly on 30th July, but on the 5th October onwards I'm getting this response, followed by a stream of `make` output until the command fails:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm

> grpc@1.24.1 install /workspace/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.1/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.1 and node@14.10.0 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

I get this response even when I rebuild from git commits that previously succeeded

I believe it could be due to Cloud Build attempting to build my NodeJS project as a different version to previously, based on the output from the most recent successful build:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm

> grpc@1.24.1 install /workspace/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
[grpc] Success: "/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote
```

I added the following line to my `package.json` in an attempt to set my NodeJS version to `v57` (`6.13.4`), but it had no effect:

```
  "engines" : { "node" : "6.13.4" },
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Preferably how I can prevent my build versions from changing as this unexpected change has cost me more hours than it should have

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an error with the node version, [check the available versions here](https://gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm)

set version, example:

```
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-12.18.3"
    args: ["install"]
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems a known issue.

the first solution could Downgrading the nodejs version to 10.18.0.

[the second solution](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/922#issuecomment-610972948)

late but anyone who must use needle for downloading:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
```

can fix this issue by installing request first:

```
npm install request
```

Then, install grpc as usual:

```
npm install grpc
```

This is because node-pre-gyp has the following code snippet during install process:

```
try {
  http_get.impl = require('request');
  http_get.type = 'request';
  log.warn("Using request for node-pre-gyp https download");
} catch (e) {
  http_get.impl = require('needle');
  http_get.type = 'needle';
  log.warn("Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download");
}
```

So request is not used because any package.json does not have request.
Pre installing request fixes this issue for me.
Important to say that all cafile options must be removed from any npm config
ssl can be set to true again as well as NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED to true.