# is there any way to run npm install and npm run build in a cloudbuild.yaml?

Tags: yaml, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have this react app, I need to deploy into a google cloud storage thru google cloud build, I'm trying to do it adding a cloudbuild.yaml and add some steps to run the npm

This is what I have:

```
steps:
  - name: bash
    script: |
      npm install --force
  - name: bash
    script: |
      npm run build
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      ["storage", "cp", "/dist/*", "gs://bucket"]
timeout: 1200s
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

but cloud build show me an error:

`Step #0: script: line 2: npm: not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-nodejs#building_with_npm_or_yarn). Before you can build your application, you must ensure that all of your project's dependencies are installed from npm or yarn.

```
steps:
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
```

If you've defined a test script in your package.json, you can configure Cloud Build to run the script by adding test to the args field:

```
steps:
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['test']
```

You can also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64288959/18265638) and github [thread](https://gist.github.com/vanduc1102/d9a9d8ae48d5eacacb45a9e193fd6e11)

Answer (score 2):

In your steps, you use `name: bash`, so you use a container with bash installed, and not NPM.

Use a container name "node:19" for instance to get a node/npm compliant container and be able to invoke NPM.